# SharePoint Survey Countdown and Click Next

Tags: javascript, development, survey, counter

We have an OOB SharePoint Survey that asks a question and if the user doesn't answer in 20 seconds, we want the survey to advance to the next question.  We have a Script Editor snippet..

[image]

and if we change the location.refresh(true); to location.href="url" it works... but we don't know what the URL would be to advance to the next question.

We want it to advance to the next question as if the .clickNextButton took place.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: I do not see a function `location.refresh(true)`. You can use `location.reload(true)`